# Suming up array gives error C programming

Tags: c

I  have write a program that calculates the number of hours worked within a specific period and prints the total number of hours, the average length of a day and an itemisation of the hours entered. First, the program must ask how many days of working hours shall be entered (max 30 days). After this, the program asks for the daily working hours. The program output shall have one decimal place of precision.

The error I am getting is that when adding all the values together for total hours worked it goes above 100000, I am not sure why.

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h> 

  int main()
  {
    float hours[30];
    float total;
    int day;
    int i ;
    float avg;
    int j;

    printf("The program calculates the total hours worked during \na specific period and the average length of a day.\n\n");
    printf("How many days:");
    scanf("%d",&day);

    for(i=0; i<day; i++){
     printf("Enter the working hours for day %d:",i+1);
     scanf("%f",&hours[i]);
     total += hours[i];

   }
    avg = total/day;

    printf("Total hours worked: %.1f\n", total);
    printf("Average length of day: %.1f\n", avg);
    printf("Hours entered:");
      for( j = 0; j < day; j++){
          printf("%.1f\t", hours[j]);
      }
 }
```

Error message from compiler
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1lAj.png)

Comment: Please include the error message into your question (as text). Thanks. It is not comming from the compiler, btw.

Answer (score 4):

`total` is not initialized here. You need to set it to `0`:

```
float total = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Worked like a charm! Will upvote you and click the correct button in a while :D

Comment: Then please be so kind to accept the answer which works for you, @MasnadNehtih.

Answer (score 3):

`float total`;

is unititialized, so you are invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Change it to.

```
float total = 0;
```